# Segfault with malloc a string in function and use it in another

Tags: c, string, memory, segmentation-fault, malloc

here is my two functions :

```
void base(char *str)
{
    char *without_spaces;
    without_spaces = remove_spaces(str);                                   
    printf("Without spaces length : %d \n", strlen(without_spaces)); // SEGFAULT HERE !
    free(without_spaces);
}

char *remove_spaces(char *source)
{
  char *result;
  int i = 0;
  result = malloc(strlen(source) + 1);
  while (*source != 0)
  {
     if (*source != ' ') {
      result[i] = *source;
      i++;
     }

     source++;
  }
  result[i] = '\0';
  // If I make the printf here it's work's
  return (result);
}
```

Here is how I call the base function (the chars provide from the stdin)

```
int main()
{
  unsigned int maxsize = 324220;
  unsigned int size;
  char *str;
  char buffer[8096];
  unsigned int  i;
  unsigned int  p;
  if ((str = malloc(maxsize + 1)) == NULL)
    return (my_error(RUNTIME_ERROR_MSG, RUNTIME_ERROR_MEMORY));
  p = 0;
  while (p < maxsize && (size = read(0, buffer, 8096)) > 0)
  {
    i = 0;
    while (i < size && p < maxsize)
    {
      str[p] = buffer[i];
      i = i + 1;
      p = p + 1;
    }
  }
  str[p] = '\0';
  base(str);
  return (0);
}
```

There are an segfault when I use this code with a really big str (approximately 500 000 chars) but it's works when I use it with less chars (like 50 000).

Why ? It's works if I remove the printf in the base function and make it in the remove space function like I have commented it.

Thank's ;)

EDIT: here it's valgrind output (with -g flag compiled)

```
==27259== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27259== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27259== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27259== Command: ../a.out
==27259== 
Without spaces length : 324987
==27259== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27259==     in use at exit: 324,221 bytes in 1 blocks
==27259==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 649,466 bytes allocated
==27259== 
==27259== LEAK SUMMARY:
==27259==    definitely lost: 324,221 bytes in 1 blocks
==27259==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27259==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27259==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27259==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27259== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==27259== 
==27259== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27259== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: What did your debugger tell you ?

Comment: are you sure `str` is properly NULL-terminated?

Comment: I have edited the main post with Valgrind output

Comment: Have you checked the return value from `malloc()` before you use it?  It can fail and return NULL — but your code assumes it is valid.  It is possible that your system won't let you allocate 0.5 MiB of data, though it is unusual.  Or you have some other operation that is messing up the heap from which `malloc()` allocates its data.

Comment: The `valgrind` output doesn't show a seg fault, so it isn't of any direct relevance to the question.  The interesting `valgrind` output would be from a run where the program crashes with the segmentation fault.

Comment: @yano My str come from stdin and I have add \0 at the end of the stdin read

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but without Valgrind it's same binary segfault

Comment: Your `valgrind` output doesn't show a segfault; it can't be the "same binary segfault".  It also seems to read just 320 KiB or so, not 500 KiB or so as claimed in the question.  It is really hard to debug code when you don't have an MCVE ([MCVE]), and when the shown output doesn't match the claimed failure.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler cat content | ./a.out > [1]    28010 done                              cat content | 
       28011 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out

Comment: @Sadek please show the code that gets the string right before calling `base`. Or even better show us a [mcve].

Comment: Now show us the output from: `valgrind ./a.out < content`.  Does it produce the error?  If so, then the output is probably interesting.  If not, then we're into Heisenbug hunting — a fun game for all the family.  At that point, the MCVE becomes crucial.  (Are you building the binary with debugging enabled (`-g` with most compilers)?  If not, do so; you'll want the extra information that gives.)

Comment: Right, I have used 500 000 chars as example but I use really 324987 chars

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's don't segfault with valgrind : ==28232== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0) and i'm getting the outptu of the printf

Comment: Welcome to the Heisenbug.  Your MCVE is very crucial.  That means the complete program, and your certification that the complete program you show crashes unless run by `valgrind` (whereupon it seems to work).

Comment: I have add the main function

Comment: You're showing `maxsize = 324220;` and trying to process 324987 bytes?  Isn't that a problem?

Comment: Buts with wc it's show 324220 length

Comment: When I run your code on a file with 357938 bytes of data, your program lists the answer as 324220.  That is, it correctly ignores the excess data that won't fit into the allocated space.  The file I used is actually a random set of month names in English, one per line, 50,000 lines.  I was testing on macOS Sierra 10.12.1 with GCC 6.2.0.  (I don't have a working `valgrind` on this machine at the moment, sadly.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't understand,on my computer it's segfault but with less chars it's works (like 50 k).

Comment: @Sadek are you able to run it with gdb ?

Comment: The small number is explicable; you don't go out of bounds of your array of size 324220 bytes.  With the bigger size, on your machine, your code is writing out of bounds, somehow, and accessing 324987 bytes.  I don't see analogous misbehaviour, but that's probably because you're using a different platform (O/S, O/S Version, C compiler, C compiler version.

Comment: After many tries it's appear that the segfault occur when my function remove_spaces is in another file of the main function and I haven't make header. Why it's make a segfault and why its work with more little amount of chars ?

Comment: Candidate problems:  1) `remove_spaces(char *source)` used before declaration.  Move definition  before use in `base()`.  2)  `result = malloc(strlen(source) + 1);` allocation not checked.  Check for valid return value.  3) `printf("Without spaces length : %d \n", strlen(without_spaces));` wrong printf specifier, use `"%zu"`, not `"%d"`.     4) Problems if `unsigned` range less than `size_t`.  Report ranges. 5) General: enable all compiler warnings and report those warnings.

Answer (score 2):

i think thoses functions a bit confusing in the logic, the function who read also does the copy, i'd prefer an aproch where there is a function to calculate the good lenght to malloc, then one to copy, and finally one to read from stdin

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static size_t   ft_strlen(const char *str)
{
    size_t      len;

    len = 0;
    while (*str != '\0')
    {
        if (*str != ' ')
            len++;
        str++;
    }
    return (len);
}

char            *delete_spaces(const char *str)
{
    const size_t        size = ft_strlen(str);
    char                *nospaces;
    size_t              p;

    if (!(nospaces = malloc(size + 1)))
        return (NULL);
    p = 0;
    while (*str)
    {
        if (*str != ' ')
            nospaces[p++] = *str;
        str++;
    }
    nospaces[p] = '\0';
    return (nospaces);
}

int             main(int ac, char **av)
{
    char    *nospaces;

    if (ac < 2)
        return (0);
    nospaces = delete_spaces(av[1]);
    printf("nospaces: %s\n", nospaces);
    free(nospaces);
    return (0);
}
```

> /a.out 'testing a string with somes spaces'
>   gives: nospaces: testingastringwithsomesspaces

then in this case you will also malloc just the good size (source - number of spaces + 1)

by the way if you compile with clang you can add:
-fsanitize=address -g3

to the compilation flags
using -Weverything -Werror
is also a very good practice when trying to find this kind of bugs

Comment: the () around my returns are just because of the coding rules i'm using